Optional word "that" could slightly change meaning of sentence?
Take the following two sentences:

I'm afraid you'll die if you do that.

I'm afraid that you'll die if you do that.


My gut feeling tells me that the first sentence is more sure of itself. The first sentence is somewhat closer in meaning to "I'm sorry but you'll die if you do that" than the second one. I would like to know if there is such a linguistic phenomenon that explains how adding an optional "clause connector" can change the global meaning of a sentence.

Why do you feel there is a difference between the two sentences? Have you come across a definition of "that" which suggests doubt?

I think both versions are capable of two meanings - "I'm sorry, but..." and "I'm fearful that..." . The version with that is just a bit more formal.

My intuition is that "I'm afraid that" can be almost meaningless - it is officialese, as in "I'm afraid that I must reject your loan application", where there is no fear or even regret. Using more words makes something more windy and meaningless, but also more official-sounding. It's all about register/tone.

The connector that is not added where you see it, but dropped where don't see it.

@dubious No. That's exactly the point. There is no "linear" definition of "that" which suggests doubt. I'm looking for something more "non-linear".

@StuartF That's interesting. In this case, both are equally meaningless, though I'd nearly always go with "that" in this context (officialese).

You write:

The first sentence is somewhat closer in meaning to "I'm sorry but you'll die if you do that"

Your ear is just being misled by the various meanings of the word afraid and the register of those meanings.
When I'm afraid has the informal snarky meaning, it isn't usually complemented by a clause headed by that.

Sorry, buddy. I'm afraid you're wrong.
Sorry, buddy. I'm afraid that you're wrong.  imperfectly idiomatic

Although you will find academic articles treating subordinate clauses in which that has been omitted as a feature of  formal, academic writing, claiming that it is not used much in colloquial conversation, they're wrong; it is just  as much a feature of colloquial conversation if not even more so: the more colloquial you get, the less likely the clause subordinator that is used.

Where's Mary?
-- I wish I knew.

So it's not so much that that is changing the meaning but that that isn't wanted by the verb afraid when it's used in snark mode.

@user405662 Yeah. It wasn't used in a sarcastic kind of way lol. The first sentence is definitely more idiomatic and that's also the reason why I'd use it in most cases. The second one just feels more literal. I also don't know why the question was migrated. I know perfectly well what I'd say. It's more of a theoretical question.

@David Well, I fail to see the context that would require politeness in "I'm sorry, but you'll die if you do that."   But this only goes to show that your examples fail, in and of themselves, to clearly establish a context which your question requires and that your sense of what these utterances mean is idiosyncratic. You may have a context in mind for those words coming out of someone's mouth, but we hardly know if your speaker is warning someone about eating a swollen can of soup or warning them that trying to jump their motorcyle across a gorge is a bad idea.
